# Spinner with ENUM values in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, enums, spinner

I'm trying to build a Spinner with values from an ENUM on it in my Xamarin application.
The way I would do it would be like this:

```
view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.my_spinner).Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, layout, Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.my_enum_array));
```

And at my `values/Strings.xml`:

```
<string-array name="my_enum_array">
<item>Enum Item 1</item>
<item>Enum Item 2</item>
</string-array>
```

But changing MyEnum the array on Strings get obsolete.

How can I bind the values to my Spinner without care which fields it has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Enum.GetValues(typeof(YourEnum))` to get all of the values for your enum. Then you can use that to create your array for your adapter.

```
var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(YOUR_ENUM));
var arrayForAdapter = enumValues.Cast<YOUR_ENUM>().Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray();
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(context, layout, arrayForAdapter);
```

You will need add a using `System.Linq`.

```
using System.Linq;
```

I haven't tried running this code, but I think it should be pretty close. Let me know if you have any issues.

Edit added a `Cast` to convert the object array into an `IEnumerable<YOUR_ENUM>`.

Comment: Even with `System.linq` added shows the message `'Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method ...`.

Comment: `Enum.GetValues` returns the archaic version of `Array` (instead of a version using generics). See the edited answer for updated code.

Comment: Also, I suspect you'll have less than 100 values so this shouldn't be an issue, but the `ArrayAdapter` will have performance problems as the array gets larger. This happens because of bridging with Java and GREF impact on the garbage collector. You can easily avoid that problem by just creating your own implementation subclassing BaseAdapter.

Comment: Works nicelly!! Many Thanks!!!
The problem now is to change the texts to a user frendly texts.
But again, thank you very much!